# Using 2 keyboards at the same time create annoying input lag

Tags: keyboard, xorg, 18.04

I have a Razer Naga mouse which has 12 side buttons they're considered a separate input device
also this issue can be replicated when using my USB keyboard and the laptop keyboard

- when typing on a single device everything is perfect
- if a key is pressed from another device the input will take like 500ms then if continued typing on the same device it's perfect
- if 20 keys are pressed from another device input will lag up to 2000ms (depends how many keys are pressed) then goes back to normal
- now you can see the frustration when using 2 input devices in essential to my workflow
- btw I think this is an xorg issue because if I logoff and in the password input field i mash as many keys from both input devices THERE IS NO LAG

had this issue in 17.10 and now in a fresh install of 18.04,
please help.
if you want i can shoot a quick video demonstration

Answer (score 2):

As of Ubuntu 20.04, gnome-shell on XOrg is broken for split keyboards in the way you describe.

Possible solutions:

1. Switch to Wayland (not tested).
2. Switch to other WM with `--replace` (fixes this specific problem but otherwise breaks gnome-shell).
3. Switch to other DE.
4. Rebuild `libmutter-6-0` package with [commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/commit/b01edc22f3cf816ec2bbc4e777fb44525a8456a8) re-applied. [More detailed instructions](https://lindholm.tk/post/1). I had to install all built packages with `sudo apt install ./*.deb` because installing only `libmutter-6-0` breaks layout switching with Caps that I set up using gnome-tweaks.

Comment: Alas, the instructions link is broken, and Internet Archive doesn't have a copy.

Comment: This comment by Osvald Lindholm contained detailed instructions that worked for me for recompiling libmutter-6-0 on Ubuntu 20.04:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1858#note_818548

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an Xorg issue. If this is an option for you: at the login screen there is a small gear where you can select "Ubuntu on Wayland". This solves the issue for me. I'm typing this on two USB keyboards right now.

The only issue is that it seems to have some lag in propagating shift. I.E. if i press shift on one board and a key on the other, it comes out unshifted, unless I hold shift for a bit.

Comment: Yeah i know but a lot of things don't work in Wayland  and frankly i've gotten used to it, and since I plan to move to Mac it doesn't bother me anymore, i guess i was looking for a xorg fix,

Comment: It used to be that Wayland was quite bad, having random lags for me. But I tried it for this question, and it's been working so far.

Comment: I've actually made the switch, and read up on wayland a bit, and now I understand why apps like gpick and shutter don't work on wayland, for security reasons, and so far so good here too

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an Xorg issue. I use unity in Ubuntu 18.04 instead of Xorg

```
sudo apt install lightdm -y
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop -y
```

Comment: Isn't xorg a display server and Unity a desktop environment, do you mean to tell me that Unity uses a different display server than GNOME?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issues on Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) with my split keyboard.

The way I solved it was by installing KDE Plasma Desktop and then logging in with Plasma. But I think any version of KDE will work. You can also try logging in with Wayland which might be pre-installed, though Wayland was causing other problems on my computer so I would suggest giving KDE a try!

Answer (score 0):

The lag disappears when the second keyboard is separated into second master using 'xinput create-master Second' and then attaching the second keyboard to it using 'xinput reattach  '.

That however creates a second mouse pointer too (which is blinking annoyingly on my screen) and each of the keyboards has their own focus. One keyboard can type into one window while the second can type to another.

Even though the lag disappeared, this is not a useful workaround unless it can be figured out how to hide the mouse pointer (moving it to the bottom right corner could be sufficient, and is easily done) and make sure both keyboards always send inputs to the same window.

Edit: the issue is not present in fvwm, where two keyboards work fine without any lags. So far I could only confirm it in Gnome.

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1754702 ?

Comment: My last comment: this is the root cause https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1154
Read comment from Oleg Smelo from June 20 2021

Comment: Recompiled mutter with changes as per suggestion from Oleg Smelov on the link above. Works like a charm!

Comment: Oh, it is FASCINATING that you can even do that, haha

Comment: trashbarg - I ended up recompiling first with the change you referenced, then with the change THAT referenced, and now it works.  Thanks!