# System Stutters when Typing

Tags: drivers, 19.10

**Symptoms:**

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10.

System experiencing micro-stuttering (less than 0.5 seconds) when typing.

Watching a video at the same time makes this more obvious as the whole video freezes for the period of the stutter. This happens regardless of where the typing occurs e.g. in chromium, in vs code or in the Activities search field. But the freeze is noticeable without video playback as well (it will then take 0.5 seconds for the character to show)

I can continue to give input during the stutter and the system will correctly interpret my input.

The issue seems to be worse when ctrl-backspacing to delete whole words, but that might be a false bias from my side.

**Checked so far:**

Ran full upgrades of all installed packages

Upgraded the kernel from the default kernel included with 19.10 to 5.4.18, due to another post which had high cpu-loads and stuttering from inputs on the default kernel. This did not remove my issues.

**System info:** 
Running Ubuntu 19.10

```
System:
  Host: Ezra Kernel: 5.4.18-050418-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.34.1 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME Z370-P v: Rev X.0x 
  serial: <root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2401 date: 07/15/2019 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-8700K bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
  Speed: 3013 MHz min/max: 800/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3077 2: 2853 
  3: 2748 4: 2714 5: 2756 6: 2745 7: 2920 8: 2762 9: 2828 10: 2720 11: 2752 
  12: 2757 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] 
  driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: amdgpu 
  resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 480 Graphics (POLARIS10 DRM 3.35.0 
  5.4.18-050418-lowlatency LLVM 9.0.0) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.18-050418-lowlatency 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 
  IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 18:31:bf:be:19:cc 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.08 TiB used: 43.87 GiB (2.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 970 EVO 500GB 
  size: 465.76 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
  ID-3: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD1001FALS-00J7B1 
  size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-4: /dev/sdc vendor: Crucial model: CT256MX100SSD1 size: 238.47 GiB 
  ID-5: /dev/sdd type: USB model: General USB Flash Disk size: 30.05 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.96 GiB used: 43.84 GiB (9.6%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C gpu: amdgpu temp: 63 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: amdgpu fan: 765 
Info:
  Processes: 342 Uptime: 42m Memory: 31.31 GiB used: 2.44 GiB (7.8%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.36
```

edit: Updated system specs after NVME-driver update and update of latest bios (issues still persist)

**Update #1:**

- Updated drivers of SSD and BIOS, no change in behavior
- Tested with nomodeset, no change in behavior
- Updated graphics drivers using (launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers), no change.
- Tested on a separate user, no change.

**Update #2:**

Tested running Wayland instead, which seems to have alleviated the issue, however, some small hickups in other areas did creep up.Will need to test more under Wayland.

**Update #3:**
Running on Wayland means the issue is completely removed and has been working well in the long-run as well.

Now testing with a cheap deltaco keyboard instead of my normal QPad Mk85 keyboard, under X11 instead of Wayland. And early 5-minute impression is that there aren't any system-stutters with this keyboard.

The following post talks about something that sounds extremely similar to my issues when using multiple keyboards at the same time. Could the mk85 be doing something funky to enable multiple keypresses at the same time, or the fact that it also carries a two port USB-hub in the same USB cable?

[Using 2 keyboards at the same time create annoying input lag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044985/using-2-keyboards-at-the-same-time-create-annoying-input-lag/1073586#1073586)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to determine what BIOS you have installed based on your logs, so please show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Here's the current BIOS, located at https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z370-P/HelpDesk_BIOS/

[image]

You also need to download the `Samsung Magician` to check your Samsung SSD's firmware. Found at https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Other SSD/HDD vendors may have a similar utility.

**Update #1:**

User updated the BIOS and SSD firmware.

**Update #2:**

User replaced the keyboard and everything is working now.

Comment: Thanks, I am sure both of those are out of date on my system. I'll give them an update and see where I land. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated the BIOS to 2401, and the SSD drivers to the latest version, issues still persist however.

Comment: @Tobyndax Thanks for trying the newer BIOS and the SSD firmware. Please show me `sysctl vm.swappiness` and tell me what version AMD drivers are installed `dpkg -l *amd*`. Also, please log into another account on the system and see if the problem persists (temporarily create a new account if need be). Do you know how to boot with `nomodeset`?

Comment: vm.swappiness = 60

As for AMD-drivers I don't know exactly which ones you are interested in, here is an excerpt of the output of the command you asked me to run:

`amd64-microcode           3.20191021.1+really3.20181128.1ubuntu2`
`firmware-amd-graphics     <none>`
`xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu 19.0.1-1ubuntu1`

I'll give a separate user and  nomodeset a go (I'll do my own research on how to properly boot with nomodeset)

Comment: @Tobyndax Look in `Software & Updates`, Additional Drivers tab, and see what version AMD drivers it may show. If you've got 19.0.1 I think there's a newer version available.

Comment: I checked for additional drivers, but nothing showing up. I gave https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers, a go as well, no luck.

Issue persists with nomodeset as well, and from a separate new user account as well

Comment: Do you have the CPU or RAM overclocked? One of the rules of troubleshooting is to strip back the hardware. Since this sounds like a desktop computer, temporarily strip back all unnecessary hardware, like sdb/sdc/sdd, any USB devices, etc. Retest.

Comment: Sure, I'll do a bare-bones test without the GPU, remove all extra hard drives all non-essential peripherals, I'll test with a different keyboard attached to a different usb port as well for good measure. (will see if I can source a ps/2 keyboard for testing as well)

Comment: @Tobyndax Keep me posted. You didn't say whether your CPU or RAM is overclocked.

Comment: I will, it will be a few days before I get the chance to test those. Thanks for the reminder about CPU and ram. I run both at stock.

Comment: @Tobyndax status please...

Comment: Status is, works well under Wayland instead of x11. Another user here had similar issues when multiple keyboards were used (and they had a funky keyboard where the numpad registered as a separate input device.)

Comment: Have been running with another keyboard now, and all issues are gone, under X11 as well. So, it's related to the keyboard somehow.

Comment: @Tobyndax Thanks for the update. I've updated my answer.