# OS display/input freezes when typing quickly

Tags: 20.04, performance

I have dualboot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Windows 10. I noticed when coding in vscode that when making functions and such the OS would lag. At first I thought it was a vscode issue, but I've learned it's actually seems to be an OS issue as it's happening as I'm typing this. If I type quickly which I often do the OS lags to catch up and then all the words I've been typing suddenly appear.

This makes for a frustrating and slow experience, where I feel like I'm on an old computer or laptop. I use Nvidia proprietary drivers but I've tried disabling them and the problem persists. If I spam asdfjhasdjf anywhere on any software including the terminal the OS will lock. If I am watching a video, the video feed will freeze and audio will keep playing.

When I boot into windows 10, I dont have this experience whatsoever. Which is aggravating. I've had linux for a few months, but unfortunately I can't really comment if the issue is new or not.

I have 16 GB of RAM, an i7 8700k CPU, and GTX 1080.

Although the website lowered the framerate so its somewhat hard to see, the beginning when I created an arrow function '=> {}' the pop-in is obvious and at the end of the gif when I spam keys. [Gif here](https://media.giphy.com/media/da7QtzVnIUzttZ2zGb/giphy.gif)

EDIT: After seeing [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208506/system-stutters-when-typing) and swapping to X.org display driver and swapping to Wayland the problem is fixed. However- I cannot change my 1440p monitor to 144hz. The screen just goes black. I also notice there is a weird delay when moving to another 144hz monitor I have, where it transitions from 60hz to 144hz after a few seconds. It seems to be the keyboard, as I put in a 15 year old keyboard and it seems to be working fine. But I dont want to use this, I want to use my mechanical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the exact same keyboard as this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252470/ubuntu-nkro-keyboard-freezes-whole-system-on-keyboard-input-n-key-rollover) here. For anyone who has the same issue, it's you could have a mechanical keyboard that's in NKRO mode, which creates this issue. Changing it to 6KRO fixed the issue.

Comment: Running out of battery caused the issue on my keyboard.